# While pinging 0.0.0.0 , it actually gives pings from 127.0.0.1 ,Why?

Tags: networking, ip

I need to know Why and Want to know,Is there any other IPs which follows this same behaviour.

and also, what if I change my virtual switch IP into 0.0.0.0.

Comment: That address is an invalid destination address. It may only be used as a source address when your host has no assigned address, e.g. DHCP request.

Comment: It sounds like you need to look at the _[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3) defines 0.0.0.0/32 as

> This host on this network

Or in other words effectively “*any ip-address on this host*” including 127.0.0.1

Comment: I would also add that `0.0.0.0` is often used when you want a program to listen on a port on all IP addresses.

Comment: @thecarpy, yes, but that doesn't put the `0.0.0.0` address in the source or destination address of any packet, it only tells the host to listen to anything. The OP is actually trying to use the address as the destination address for actual packets, and that is not allowed.

Comment: "0.0.0.0/32" can be used when opening a socket to select "all IP addresses on this host". It isn't usually a valid destination address though.

Comment: A subquestion: How does `ping 0.0.0.0` 'resolve' (or is it 'map'?) the special address 0.0.0.0 to "(any IP address of) the local host on the local network" (f.i. 127.0.0.1)? AFAICT there appears to be no reverse mapping: on my Void Linux box, `nslookup 127.0.0.1` returns `localhost`, while `nslookup 0.0.0.0` returns NXDOMAIN.

Comment: @ack what a reverse lookup returns is a different question altogether. Unless you add 0.0.0.0 to /etc/hosts nothing but an error  **should** be returned for such a lookup, as no single valid host name can be assigned